# How to show correctly a single <UL> inside a ROW class in Boostrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I am creating a web page where i want to show multiple rows of images.  I am using Bootstrap 3.3.7 and have the following code. What is happening is that when using a col-md3, the last images are not show correctly.  I want to have them in the same row, starting from left to right, but they are in the middle of the row or some other position. [image]

```
<div class="staff-picked-posts padding-top-70 background-color-gray padding-bottom-40" id="chennal-page">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="slide tab-pane active" id="l">
                <div class="">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="row">
                            <ul class="staff-picked-videos">
                                <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="post-details">
                                        <div class="overlay-inner-image">                                               
                                                <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/o3Kbc-LSGvI/hqdefault.jpg" alt="">
                                                <a a="" class="inner-image-overlay" href="/Home/Detail/41/these-athletes-are-incredibly-angry-want-to-check-out-their-reactions"></a>                                                
                                                <div class="watch-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Watch Later">
                                                    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                                </div>
                                         </div>
                                        <div class="image-content background-color-light-green">
                                            <h3><a href="/Home/Detail/41/these-athletes-are-incredibly-angry-want-to-check-out-their-reactions">These athletes are incredibly angry.  Want to check out their reactions?</a></h3>
                                            <!--<p>kocco.co<i class="fa fa-check-circle-o trending-post"></i></p>-->
                                            <p class="margin-bottom-0">4/30/2017 <span><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> 0 </span><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> 0</p>
                                        </div>
                                     </div>
                                 </li>
                                <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="post-details">
                                        <div class="overlay-inner-image">                                               
                                                <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/H2EXKlJ0pfI/hqdefault.jpg" alt="">
                                                <a a="" class="inner-image-overlay" href="/Home/Detail/44/most-shocking-boxing-moments-want-to-check"></a>                                                
                                                <div class="watch-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Watch Later">
                                                    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                                </div>
                                         </div>
                                        <div class="image-content background-color-light-green">
                                            <h3><a href="/Home/Detail/44/most-shocking-boxing-moments-want-to-check">Most Shocking Boxing moments. Want to check?                </a></h3>
                                            <!--<p>kocco.co<i class="fa fa-check-circle-o trending-post"></i></p>-->
                                            <p class="margin-bottom-0">4/30/2017 <span><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> 0 </span><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> 0</p>
                                        </div>
                                     </div>
                                 </li>
                                <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="post-details">
                                        <div class="overlay-inner-image">                                               
                                                <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3jT_q7dt-cM/hqdefault.jpg" alt="">
                                                <a a="" class="inner-image-overlay" href="/Home/Detail/45/top-10-crazy-moments-in-sports"></a>                                                
                                                <div class="watch-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Watch Later">
                                                    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                                </div>
                                         </div>
                                        <div class="image-content background-color-light-green">
                                            <h3><a href="/Home/Detail/45/top-10-crazy-moments-in-sports">Top 10 Crazy Moments in Sports                              </a></h3>
                                            <!--<p>kocco.co<i class="fa fa-check-circle-o trending-post"></i></p>-->
                                            <p class="margin-bottom-0">4/30/2017 <span><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> 0 </span><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> 0</p>
                                        </div>
                                     </div>
                                 </li>
                                <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="post-details">
                                        <div class="overlay-inner-image">                                               
                                                <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/RvklO0O3BcY/hqdefault.jpg" alt="">
                                                <a a="" class="inner-image-overlay" href="/Home/Detail/46/top-20-funny-moments-in-soccer"></a>                                                
                                                <div class="watch-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Watch Later">
                                                    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                                </div>
                                         </div>
                                        <div class="image-content background-color-light-green">
                                            <h3><a href="/Home/Detail/46/top-20-funny-moments-in-soccer">Top 20 funny moments In Soccer                              </a></h3>
                                            <!--<p>kocco.co<i class="fa fa-check-circle-o trending-post"></i></p>-->
                                            <p class="margin-bottom-0">4/30/2017 <span><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> 0 </span><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> 0</p>
                                        </div>
                                     </div>
                                 </li>
                                <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="post-details">
                                        <div class="overlay-inner-image">                                               
                                                <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_c55cW6UGP0/hqdefault.jpg" alt="">
                                                <a a="" class="inner-image-overlay" href="/Home/Detail/50/ronaldinho-making-amazing-plays-in-soccer"></a>                                                
                                                <div class="watch-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Watch Later">
                                                    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                                </div>
                                         </div>
                                        <div class="image-content background-color-light-green">
                                            <h3><a href="/Home/Detail/50/ronaldinho-making-amazing-plays-in-soccer">Ronaldinho making amazing plays in soccer.                  </a></h3>
                                            <!--<p>kocco.co<i class="fa fa-check-circle-o trending-post"></i></p>-->
                                            <p class="margin-bottom-0">4/30/2017 <span><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> 0 </span><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> 0</p>
                                        </div>
                                     </div>
                                 </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT 1**:

ANSWER THANKS TO [Shariqkhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5749479/shariqkhan)

```
/*screen-sm*/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
.staff-picked-videos .col-sm-4:nth-child(3n+1) { 
    clear: both;
}
}
/*screen-md*/
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
staff-picked-videos .col-md-3:nth-child(4n+1) { 
    clear: both;
}
}
/*screen-lg corresponds with col-lg*/
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
staff-picked-videos .col-md-3:nth-child(4n+1) { 
    clear: both;
}
}
```

Comment: `columns` should be placed the directly inside the` row`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first column on every new row should clear i.e they should have clear:both in their css markup.
In your example the first column (These athletes are...), 5th column (Ronaldinho making...) should clear floats.

So you should add this CSS rule:

```
.staff-picked-videos .col-md-3:nth-child(4n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  It solved my problem.  This community is great!!

Comment: maybe you can help me with other issue.  I am not an expert in CSS.  I also need to fix the same issue when screen size is col-md-4.  When screen size is col-md-3 i need to show 4 images, and when screen size is col-md-4 i need to show 3 images.  What else do i need to add in my CSS rules in order to have both fixed?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: I was able to fix it by using Media Queries.

Comment: Glad to know that it helped. I myself have learned a LOT from Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I think the expected behaviour is:

```
CardA  CardB  CardC  CardD
CardE  ...
```

Right?

If yes, the root cause of your problem is: The height of cards are different. In your case, CardA's height is larger than CardB, when CardB is placed  in new row, browser will try to find the most left and most top position (unfortunately, "top" has higher priority than "left", which is the behaviour of `float` -- the underline CSS rule used by `col-md-3`). So, if CardA's height is 110 and CardB&CardC&CardD's height is 100, the result would be:

```
 CardA  CardB  CardC  CardD
        CardE  ...
```

If CardA's height is 110 and CardB's height is 105 and CardC&CardD's height is 100, the result would be:

```
CardA  CardB  CardC  CardD
              CardE  ...
```

To implement your expected behaviour, cards should be placed in columns, not rows. For example, CardA and CardE should be put into one `<div>`, CardB and CardF should be put into another `<div>` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your columns will not have class `col-md-3`. Instead they will have `col-md-2` where first column will have an additional class `col-md-offset-1`

Your column structure would look like this -

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```

The offset adds space to the left of your element.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the first li height is increased due to that only this issue is caused due to lengthy title please use excerpt css for title https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-overflow . You can set maximum height to the post and also give overflow hidden or please use excerpt css to the title of the post if the height of all post is adjusted by maximum height css your issue will be fixed.